# rabbitmq-c send nlohmann json

Tags: c++, mfc, base64, nlohmann-json, rabbitmq-c

Want to send image through RabbitMQ-C but the image file too big. Receiver cannot retrieve the image. So, I converted image to base64 then put it in JSON.

```
const char *msg;


FILE *image1;
    if (image1 = fopen(path, "rb")) {
        fseek(image1, 0, SEEK_END); //used to move file pointer to a specific position
                                    // if fseek(0 success, return 0; not successful, return non-zero value
                                    //SEEK_END: end of file
        
        length = ftell(image1); //ftell(): used to get total size of file after moving the file pointer at the end of the file
        sprintf(tmp, "size of file: %d  bytes", length);

//convert image to base64
        std::string line;
        std::ifstream myfile;
        myfile.open(path, std::ifstream::binary);
        std::vector<char> data((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(myfile)), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>() );
        std::string base64_encode(unsigned char const* bytes_to_encode, unsigned int in_len);
        std::string code = base64_encode((unsigned char*)&data[0], (unsigned int)data.size());
        
//convert std::string to const char 
        const char* base64_Image = code.c_str();
        

        
        json j ;
    
        
        j.push_back("Title");
        j.push_back("content");
        j.push_back(base64_Image);
        
        std::string sa = j.dump();

        msg = sa.c_str();       //convert std::string to const char*
        
    }
    else {
        return;
    }
```

Using RabbitMQ-C to send the message(msg) to receiver but failed
[error point to here]

is const char* cannot use amqp_cstring_bytes(msg) to convert to amqp_bytes_t??

```
    respo = amqp_basic_publish(conn, 1, amqp_cstring_bytes(exchange), amqp_cstring_bytes(routing_key),0, 0, NULL, amqp_cstring_bytes(msg));
```

and get this error

````
If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.```


Anyone know how to send image as JSON using RabbitMQ-C & C++ ?
````

Comment: How did you determine the image was "too big" to receive? If that truly was the issue, base64-encoding something increases its size by 33%, so this will only aggravate the problem.

Comment: Thanks @Botje for your reply. Actually I'm not too sure what's the matter makes receiver cannot decode the image i sent. The image I want to send mostly around 400kb but my base64 string more than 50k characters. previously i used RapidJSON to create JSON object  ```Write.String(base64,255, true); ``` but the character is more than 255. Now i'm using nlohmann json , it allows me to create and get complete base64 string in JSON but unable to send through RabbitMQ. Do you know any mistake i have done in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`amqp_cstring_bytes`](https://rabbitmq-c.docsforge.com/master/api/amqp_cstring_bytes/) expects a C string, which is normally terminated by a NUL byte. Your PNG file is almost guaranteed to contain a NUL byte, so that explains why your message got cut off midway through.

As for the code in your paste: the pointer returned by `sa.c_str()` is only valid while `sa` is alive and unmodified. Once you exit the block containing `sa`'s definition, the variable is dead and buried.

Instead, get a buffer of the appropriate size with [`amqp_bytes_alloc`](https://rabbitmq-c.docsforge.com/master/api/amqp_bytes_malloc/) and return that:

```
amqp_bytes_t bytes = amqp_bytes_malloc(sa.length());
strncpy((char *)bytes.bytes, sa.c_str(), sa.length());
```

then pass the `bytes` object to `amqp_basic_publish`. Don't forget to [`ampqp_bytes_free`](https://rabbitmq-c.docsforge.com/master/api/amqp_bytes_free/) it when you're done.

Comment: i have tried this and i get this error ```Error C2664 'char *strncpy(char *,const char *,std::size_t)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'void *' to 'char *' ```
 when using ```strncpy(bytes.bytes, sa.c_str(), sa.length());```

Comment: You need to add a cast to make that error go away. See edit.